# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/RunJar

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am basically trying to run a mad reduce job on a remote node and i am facing the exception mentioned below. Did any one go through the same issue? I am posting the scipt I'm using to set class path and launch the job.

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk7
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0
export CONF=/home/hadoop/p2Cluster/conf
export PATH=$CONF:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=.:$CONF:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$CONF
echo "classpath=$CLASSPATH"
#
C2=""
JARS=`find $HADOOP_HOME -name '*hadoop*.jar'`
for j in $JARS
do
echo "$j"
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$j
C2=$C2,$j
done

client=******
jobQueueName=default
JAR=****.jar
export HADOOP_CLASS_PATH=$CLASSPATH
hadoop jar $JAR $client  interactive 2 groupA.txt groupB.txt
#
#java $client  interactive 2 groupA.txt groupB.txt $jobQueueName
exit 0



error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/RunJar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: Are you sure that your script is using all the hadoop jars required. Could you also check if hadoop-core.jar which is present in the hadoop home folder.

Comment: @KSNidhin i am using hadoop 2.4.0 so i don't have hadoop-core.jar. Instead i am using                                                           hadoop-common-2.4.0-sources.jar
hadoop-common-2.4.0-test-sources.jar                                   hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.4.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

1. Change HADOOP_HOME to HADOOP_PREFIX
2. Make sure hadoop picks up correct java version
3. You can configure necessary java in hadoop-env.conf
4. Try again $ hadoop version